# arabic characters appears as ??????? ?????? in json format. iphone

Tags: iphone, getjson

I am getting Arabic characters as ????? in return from JSON.

Can anyone tel me how to get Arabic characters right in JSON format?

EDIT:
I am using English language. I also have tried encoding it to UTF8.

Many Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: It depends on what language you are using to get your data into the JSON format. You have a multibyte character encoding issue on your hand. Since you haven't mentioned what your originating language for the JSON data is it is hard to help. It sounds like you've either not UTF8 encoded the data or it's not decoding in UTF8 coming from JSON.

Comment: I am using English language. I also have tried encoding it to UTF8.

Answer (score 4):

I have searched the solution by myself.

Solution is just call the set names to utf8 after connecting to DB like this:

$host_link = mysql_connect(DBASE_HOST, DBASE_USER, DBASE_PWD);
if (!$host_link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   exit;

}
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8; ");

Hope this will help some others.
Naveed

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me. For those using PDO, this solution helped: http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/